# Load RDB file generated by Redis 4 into Redis 5

Tags: redis

I'm trying load a RDB file generated by Redis 4 into Redis 5 but no data is visible.

I simply copied the RDB file to the location Redis 5 expects (I double and triple checked it's the correct location), start Redis 5 and it starts without error:

````
27066:C 06 Aug 2019 20:22:34.304 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
27066:C 06 Aug 2019 20:22:34.304 # Redis version=5.0.5, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=27066, just started
27066:C 06 Aug 2019 20:22:34.304 # Configuration loaded
27067:M 06 Aug 2019 20:22:34.306 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 1024).
                _._
           _.-``__ ''-._
      _.-``    `.  `_.  ''-._           Redis 5.0.5 (00000000/0) 64 bit
  .-`` .-```.  ```\/    _.,_ ''-._
 (    '      ,       .-`  | `,    )     Running in standalone mode
 |`-._`-...-` __...-.``-._|'` _.-'|     Port: 6379
 |    `-._   `._    /     _.-'    |     PID: 27067
  `-._    `-._  `-./  _.-'    _.-'
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |           http://redis.io
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'
      `-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'
          `-._        _.-'
              `-.__.-'

27067:M 06 Aug 2019 20:22:34.307 # Server initialized
27067:M 06 Aug 2019 20:22:34.574 * DB loaded from disk: 0.268 seconds
27067:M 06 Aug 2019 20:22:34.574 * Ready to accept connections
````

The `0.26 seconds` is actually an indication that it indeed loads (or tries to load) the RDB file. When no RDB file is there, it says `0.00 seconds`.

But then there's no data:

```
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
(empty list or set)
```

And what's super strange is that even when I set a key and call `save`, the RDB file from Redis 4 doesn't change:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set foo bar
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "foo"
127.0.0.1:6379> save
OK
(0.51s)
127.0.0.1:6379> exit

$ ls /var/redis/
total 27M
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Aug  6 20:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4.0K Aug  6 18:40 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  27M Aug  6 20:32 redis.rdb
```

And when I restart Redis, the "foo" key is still there, so it must be saved somewhere in the RDB file.

Does Redis 5 just ignore all data in the RDB file, that was created by Redis 4, and append it's own data?
If so, why is there no notice of it during startup, something like "warning: RDB file from previous version of Redis found, ignoring..."

EDIT

Ok, I found the following statement [here](https://rdb.fnordig.de/version_history.html):

> An RDB file is forwards compatible. An older dump file format will always work with a newer version of Redis.

So it *should* work. But why does it not?

Comment: You mentioned that you triple checked the location of the file redis.rdb, but the default redis backup file is dump.rdb https://redis.io/topics/persistence#snapshotting

Comment: Yeah, but I set `dbfilename redis.rdb`. :)

Comment: Is it possible that the keys in the RDB are not in database #0? Try running `INFO` and looking and the keyspace statistics.

Comment: @ItamarHaber YES! That was it! Incredible that I missed that... please add an answer that I can accept! :)

Comment: @ManuelMeurer it was a lucky guess :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the information you've provided indicates that the RDB was indeed loaded.

However. Depending on your data, the keys may be stored in different logical databases and `KEYS *` is run only on the default database (0). Instead, try executing the `INFO` command and examining the 'Keyspace' section to see if your keys are stored in different logical databases.